# What is the best agile development platform for a small team?

Tags: svn, agile

We are a small team that develop application using different language and platform (Visual Studio, Matlab and GNU C Compiler). The development team are in different location (USA and Europe)

We need a version control system and also software to agile project management.

I know about SVN +Trac + Agilo. Is there any better solution?

Regards

Edit: I want to host all software by ourselves and do not use a hosting service. We do not want that our source code goes out of company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a small team, you can use Rally Software's free version of their Agile project management tools.  It is free for up to 10 users.  We are using it and while we may not use every feature, it has worked well as a project management tool.  They do have a bunch of tutorials (I was new to the Agile philosophy, so they were very useful to me, especially coming from much more heavyweight project management).   There are a few limitations with the free version, but we haven't hit any of them yet.  We are a team of 3, and it has greatly helped us to stay focused and plan out work, using sprints/iterations of 2 weeks long.  Here's a link to the free community edition: [Rally free community edition](http://www.rallydev.com/agile_products/editions/community/)

And it is truly free.  I get maybe weekly emails from them about their services, but that's it.  One person becomes the admin user, and then you add the other people.  (edit: btw, I don't work for the company, just wanted to be clear in case that's questioned.)

Answer (score 3):

[Atlassian JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) + Greenhopper et al. For $10 for teams under 10.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about better, but my team is using [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)+[redmine_backlogs](http://www.redminebacklogs.net/)+SVN. So far it is working well for us. And you can't beat free.

Answer (score 1):

We're very happy with [PivotalTracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com) for managing our User Stories and using git with [github](http://www.github.com) for version control. Both integrate nicely (github automatically changes the status of your User Stories on commit and adds a link to the commit as a comment to the story).

Comment: I've also used Pivotal Tracker before. Great tool!